# How to run parallel suites programmatically with Testng?

Tags: testng

I want to run different test suites in parallel through code not from testng.xml file.

```
 //Creating virtual xml file from code
 List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
            for (String dealerID : dealerList) {

                String suiteName = dealerID;

                XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
                suite.setName(suiteName);

                XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
                test.setName("TestID-" + dealerID);
                test.addParameter("DataString", DataString);

                List<XmlClass> classes = new ArrayList<XmlClass>();

            // Adding multiple classes
            for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
                classes.add(i, new XmlClass(al.get(i).toString()));

            }

                test.setXmlClasses(classes);
                test.setAllowReturnValues(true);
                suites.add(suite);
            }

            // Running testng
            TestNG tng = new TestNG();
            tng.setXmlSuites(suites);
            tng.run();
```

Above code will run all the suites in series but I want to run them parallel.

Answer (score 4):

```
suite.setParallel(XmlSuite.ParallelMode.CLASSES);
suite.setThreadCount(10);
```

There are other options for parallel mode - tests, methods etc... Look them up at the api overview.

You can look up the details at -- https://jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master-6.11-g1e1d341-83/javadoc/index.html?org/testng/

Comment: Not working, only one thread is initiated every time, no parallel threads.

Comment: Try setting it on the testng instance - tng.setParallel(ParallelMode.CLASSES);

Comment: Not worked. TestNG is bypassing `setParallel` method and running the tests in series.

Answer (score 0):

I face some problem and found this solution, this code should worked

```
suite.parallel = ParallelMode.METHODS
suite.threadCount = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() // or whatever u want
```

Answer (score 0):

`suite.setSuiteThreadPoolSize(<number of your suite>)`
This line will allow to run each suite in a different thread. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To run parallel the xml suite programmatically, use `.setSuiteThreadPoolSize(threadNumberHere)`:

```
// Running testng
TestNG tng = new TestNG();
tng.setXmlSuites(suites);
tng.setSuiteThreadPoolSize(suites.size());
tng.run();
```